# Can't link pads

Tags: gstreamer

I'm writing an app for android using gstreamer 1.0. I need to display video stream and some times, as required, to write the same stream to file. Now i'm in practic with manualy linking pads. 
I've got this code:

```
 gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data->video_pipeline),udpsrc,rtph264depay,avdec_h264,/*videorate,*/clockoverlay,tee,queue_video_sink,queue_file_sink,NULL);

  if (!gst_element_link_filtered (udpsrc,rtph264depay,udpsrc_caps))     
GST_ERROR ("Can't link udpsrc and rtph264depay with caps");
  }

  if (!gst_element_link_many (rtph264depay,avdec_h264,/*videorate,*/clockoverlay,tee,NULL)){
      GST_ERROR ("Can't link many to tee");
  }

gst_object_unref (G_OBJECT(videorate_src_pad));//Возможно получится ошибка с пямятью
gst_caps_unref(videorate_caps);///Освобождаем caps


#if 1
    if(!gst_element_add_pad(tee,pad_surface_src))
        GST_ERROR("Cant add pad to tee");


    tee_src_pad_template =  gst_element_class_get_pad_template(GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS(tee),"src_%u");
    pad_surface_src = gst_element_request_pad(tee,tee_src_pad_template,NULL,NULL);

   if(!pad_surface_src){
    g_printerr ("Can't obtain request pad src for tee.\n");
   }

    pad_surface_sink = gst_element_get_static_pad(autovideosink,"sink");
    if(!pad_surface_sink){
        g_printerr ("Can't obtain request pad sink for autovideosink.\n");
       }


    if (gst_pad_link (pad_surface_src,pad_surface_sink)!=GST_PAD_LINK_OK){
        g_printerr ("Tee could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref (data->video_pipeline);
        return -1;
    }
    gst_object_unref(pad_surface_sink);
#endif
```

all pads are initialized, but gst_pad_link does not returns GST_PAD_LINK_OK. Do you know why? May be i can't to link tee and autovideosink directly, may be i need some queue? but queue do more latency.

Comment: gst_pad_link returns GST_PAD_LINK_WRONG_HIERARCHY

Comment: At which Link do you get that error?

Comment: Try removing where `if(!gst_element_add_pad(tee,pad_surface_src))
        GST_ERROR("Cant add pad to tee");` and let the request pad creation automatically create it. Be sure to declare it as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok. I just did not add autovideosink to pipeline.